# How do I make a custom UI for NextAuth.js (with AWS Cognito)?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, authorization, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to have a custom UI for AWS Cognito + [NextAuth.js](https://next-auth.js.org/)? When I call the API using NextAuth.js, [I get this (subjectively ugly) screen with nothing but a button to redirect you to the real AWS Cognito sign-in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n9iM.png).

The AWS Cognito sign-in page is alright, but I wish it was possible to skip all of this and have a custom sign-in page/form, is anything like that possible?

Comment: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages

Comment: @brc-dd Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

well, don't know if that's what you're looking but here follows a sample:
https://ntalam.com/2022/06/29/nextjs-nextauth-cognito-customized-login-page/, this tutorial is rather incomplete, but is shows more or less how it works. like the signin is not imported and it's missing the html and css but anyway if you have any doubts just leave in the coments.

Comment: The issue I was facing was resolved with the comment from brc-dd - but thank you for taking the time out for sending this!

Comment: I will finish that tutorial. Shame on me