# Next Auth setup with AWS cognito in Next js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-cognito

So after hours of brainstroming around this . I have't found any solution of doc related to this can anyone assist me step wise how we can do authorization in NextAuth with AWS cognito in Next 13 latest version with the credentials.

I Want a demo code to integrate Next auth with Aws cognito  in next js 13 with user credentials

Comment: I think this is duplicated here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70127769/how-do-i-make-a-custom-ui-for-nextauth-js-with-aws-cognito